# Find largest X pos value in QGraphicsItems

Tags: c++, qt

How can I loop through a set of Qt QGraphicsItems and find the max X value within the graph items selected. I have a function which seems to work but i recall it not being ideal to set the min value to NULL. The only reason im doing that is because otherwise the value returns something insanely far away. I just don't feel like im doing this the most efficient way. Keep in mind im taking into consideration the width of the actual graph item itself.

```
float max = NULL;
    foreach (QGraphicsItem* item, items) {
        if (!item) continue;
        if (item->type() == NexusBlockItem::Type) {
            float x = item->pos().x() + item->sceneBoundingRect().width()*.5;
            if (max == NULL) max = x;
            if (x > max) {
                max = x;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a function which seems to work but i recall it not being ideal
>   to set the min value to NULL.

It's not actually possible to set a floating point value to NULL, since only pointers can be NULL in C++ and float is not a pointer type.  What you're likely actually doing there is initializing max to 0.0f (because NULL is typically defined as 0), but conceptually it doesn't make any sense, and of course it will mess up your result if any of your actual x positions are less than zero.

As far as how to do it better, you have two options that I can think of:

1) Add a separate maximum_value_is_set variable to track when your max variable is not initialized yet.

```
float max;  // not initialized here, because...
bool maximum_value_is_set = false;  // we'll keep track of it this way instead

[...]

float x = item->pos().x() + item->sceneBoundingRect().width()*.5;
if ((maximum_value_is_set == false)||(x > max)) {
   max = x;
   maximum_value_is_set = true;
}
```

2) or, alternatively, you could just set the default value of max to the smallest possible floating point value:

```
float max = -FLT_MAX;
[...]
```

... that way any conceivable x value will be greater than the original value of max.

Btw...

```
 float x = item->pos().x() + item->sceneBoundingRect().width()*.5;
```

Why the *.5 there?  It looks like this code computes the center the the rectangle, but according to your graphic, you are more interested in the right side (in which case I think you'd want to get rid of the *.5).

Comment: The `bool` flag is a bit of an overkill, I usually use the second approach with `std::numeric_limits<type>.max()` because I can never remember these pesky C macros. According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits), it's called `FLT_MAX`, not `FLOAT_MAX`, and in C++11 one should simply use `std::numeric_limits<float>.lowest()` instead of `-max()`.

Comment: The reason for the .5 is because the anchor point for each graphics item is set to be the center of the bounding rectangle. So i need to compensate for that and find the furthest right edge of the graphics items.

Answer (score 0):

this code is for your items you shared.

```
float max = 0;
        foreach (QGraphicsItem* item, items) {
            if (!item) continue;
            if (item->type() == NexusBlockItem::Type) {
                float x = item->boundingRect().width();
                if (x > max) {
                    max = x;
                }
            }
```

but if your second item or others shifted to more right other than

item->boundingRect().windth();  is not give correct value.

what is the max value of "X"? is it biggest item's width or scene Rectangle's width?